# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: запятая

А если вдруг случится загрустить, посмотрите на своих маленьких очаровательных детей: грусть сразу исчезнет.

Нужна ли запятая перед "если"? И нужно ли обособить слово "вдруг"?

Answer (score 1):

"Вдруг" - это обычное обстоятельство, запятая не нужна. Перед "если" запятая не нужна. А вот после слова "детей" надо поставить не двоеточие, а тире, так как здесь показана быстрая смена событий.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Двоеточие поставила не случайно. В школе правило учили: "Если во второй части БСП содержится дополнение к первой (можно подставить "и увидел, и услышал, и почувствовал что"), то ставим двоеточие". Я думаю, здесь как раз можно применить это правило: посмотрите на детей, и вы увидите, что грусть сразу исчезнет. Быстрая смена событий - это же, например: "Сыр выпал - с ним была плутовка такова". Разве похоже на моё предложение? Хотя, возможно, я неправильно рассуждаю.

Comment: Правильно Вы рассуждаете. Здесь нет быстрой смены событий, а ставится пояснительное двоеточие, раскрывающее целесообразность действия, выраженного глаголом "посмотрите". Также возможна подстановка по Вашему правилу: "А если вдруг случится загрустить, посмотрите на своих маленьких очаровательных детей,  и вы увидите, что грусть сразу исчезнет.

Comment: Уважаю мнение коллеги, но не стал бы категорично возражать против того, что здесь нет быстрой смены событий. Она есть, и со скоростью света (300 000 км/сек): посмотрите - и грусть исчезнет. Кроме того,здесь есть еще и так называемое "неожиданное присоединение". Так что тире очень даже уместно, в то время как двоеточие, возможно, допустимо, но с большой натяжкой.

Comment: "Посмотрите - и грусть исчезнет". Это ССП, и тем не менее разделительно тире ставится в качестве неосновного знака. И быстрая смена событий здесь имеется в наличии, но главное - мы грамматически и интонационно можем это выразить. Нераспространенное предложение легко делится на две фразы: повышение тона - пауза - понижение тона, и такая интонация однозначно соответствует тире. Но в нашем случае не так. В нашем случае БСП состоит из СПП и простого предложения, причем простое предложение поясняет содержание СПП. В устной речи при этом делается понижение тона с предупредительной паузой.

Answer (score 0):

Союз *а* в начале предложения запятой не отделяется (ни от придаточного предложения, ни от вводного слова, ни от деепричастного оборота).

В середине предложения запятая после *а* ставится, если изъятие или перестановка придаточного предложения, вводного слова, деепричастного оборота возможны: *Не год, а, если учесть его состояние, десять лет прожил он за одну ночь* (не год, а десять лет).

Если изъятие или перестановка невозможны, запятая не ставится: *Разговор остался незаконченным, а когда он вернулся, пропала охота продолжать его* (нельзя сказать "а пропала охота").

Наречие *вдруг* вводным словом не бывает, не обособляется. Возможно авторское обособление, но для него подошли бы интонационные тире, а не запятые: А если - вдруг - случится загрустить... (то есть загрустить, конечно, невозможно, это просто невероятно, но вдруг, мало ли). По правилам же обособление не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!